# How to display a StackedInline item from a Model in Django?

Tags: python, django

i want to get the value of my field "is_verified" from aStakedInline model of my Post model

```py
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('title', 'author', 'words', 'date', 'is_verified')
        list_filter = ('date', 'author')

        def is_verified(self, obj):
            # HERE MY UNKNOWN CODE TO GET IS_VERIFIED VALUE FROM VerifiedPost Model

        def words(self, obj):
            return len(obj.content.split())


    class AccountInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = Profile
        can_delete = False
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'


    class PostInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = VerifiedPost
        can_delete = False
        verbose_name_plural = 'Verified'
```

models.py

```python
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class VerifiedPost(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If anyone can help me

Comment: `obj.verified_post.is_verified` seems to be a fit. It doesn't work?

Comment: Why don't the `Post` model has an `is_verified` field? It looks like this is "overcomplicated" modeling.

Comment: because i separate to make permission specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your modeling is wrong. You should only have a Post model, then add `is_verified` field to it. If you want to separate them to be permission specific, use Django's ORM:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(is_verified=False)

verified_posts = Post.objects.filter(is_verified=True)
```

They are separate now. But if you still want to continue doing it your way, try this:

I dont know what `obj` is, so:

If obj is a `VerifiedPost` instance: `return obj.is_verified`

If obj is a `Post` instance:

```
verified_post = obj.verifiedpost
if verified_post:
    return verified_post.is_verified
```